# kill after sleep

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, sleep

i couldnt make my program sleep() after using kill(pid,SIGTERM)
what can i do ?

The code i'm using:

```
kill(PID_of_Process_to_be_killed,SIGTERM);
sleep(5); --> this is not working
sleep(5); --> this is working
```

the solution for now is:

```
kill(PID_of_Process_to_be_killed,SIGTERM);
sleep(sleep(5));
```

but why the first sleep after kill return 0 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sleep()` call may be terminating early due to receiving a signal. Check the return value. If it's positive, you might want to `sleep()` again on that value. From http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/:

> If the sleep() function returns because the requested time has elapsed,
>   the value returned will be zero.  **If the sleep() function returns due to
>   the delivery of a signal, the value returned will be the unslept amount
>   (the requested time minus the time actually slept) in seconds**

Comment: In this case, the signal is plausibly SIGCHLD (although that would interrupt the first sleep in the code in the question, I'd think). Could be anything, though.

Answer (score 3):

Well unless you handle the signal, SIGTERM is death.

If its another process or thread sending the signal sleep returns EINTR.

If you're using the standard library instead of direct system call (you probably are) sleep returns -1 and errno = EINTR.

Comment: for some reason after sending a kill with SIGTERM using the original handler, i can't use a sleep function. i manage to use it before but not after the kill...
do you know why this happens ?

    kill(PID_of_Process_to_be_killed,SIGTERM); 
    sleep(5); --> this is not working
    sleep(5); --> this is working

Comment: what does ERRNO contain? what does sleep return?

Comment: the first sleep return 5 - meaning it didn't do anything.
and the second sleep(5) return 0 - meaning he sleep 5 seconds.

"errno = EINTER"

for now i am using this sleep(sleep(5)) - but i dont think its the right solution...

Comment: The right solution if everything is handled via signal is: x = 5; do { x = sleep(x); } while (x > 0);